# Simple mutex and conditional variable signal in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm new to multithreading in C so I made a toy program that uses a mutex and a conditional variable to communicate between two threads. `do_work` performs a task every 1 second (task could take longer than 1 second). Is this implementation free from deadlocks and race conditions? Anything else I might be missing?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include "errors.h"

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int predicate_value = 0;

void *do_work(void *work) {
    int status = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        status = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (status != 0) {
            err_abort(status, "Lock mutex");
        }
        while (predicate_value == 0) {
            printf("%s\n", "waiting");
            status = pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
            if (status != 0) {
                err_abort(status, "Wait on condition");
            }
        }
        if (predicate_value != 0) {
            printf("doing some work: %d\n", i);
            ++i;
            predicate_value = 0;
        }
        status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        if (status != 0) {
            err_abort(status, "Unlock mutex");
        }
    }
}

int main () {
    int status = 0;
    pthread_t work_thread_id;
    status = pthread_create(&work_thread_id, NULL, do_work, NULL);
    if (status != 0) {
        err_abort(status, "Create work thread");
    }
    while (1) {
        if (predicate_value == 0) {
            status = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            if (status != 0) {
                err_abort(status, "Lock mutex main");
            }
            printf("%s\n", "changed value");
            predicate_value = 1;
            status = pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
            if (status != 0) {
                err_abort(status, "signal condition");
            }
            status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            if (status != 0) {
                err_abort(status, "Unlock mutex main");
            }
            printf("%s\n", "time to sleep");            
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 4 → 3. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: `int main(void)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Needs volatile keyword

The way your program is written, `predicate_value` needs to be a `volatile int` instead of a normal `int`.  This is because you are reading it **without locking the mutex** in `main()`, and writing to it in `do_work()` from another thread.

Another way to avoid the problem is to ensure that you only ever read the variable with the mutex locked.

Comment: made the change - now I won't need the volatile keyword, right? Also, having a third thread also signal based on the conditional from another method (like in the main method here) shoudn't induce any priority inversion if all threads have the same priority, right?

Comment: `volatile` has nothing to do with atomic access. The problem of threads using a shared variable is about many threads accessing the same variable, and has to be solved with mutexes. `volatile` is for hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated version as suggested by [JS1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/58193/js1) without the volatile keyword but making sure the mutex is locked in this case.

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include "errors.h"

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int predicate_value = 0;

void *do_work(void *work) {
    int status = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        status = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (status != 0) {
            err_abort(status, "Lock mutex");
        }
        while (predicate_value == 0) {
            printf("%s\n", "waiting");
            status = pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
            if (status != 0) {
                err_abort(status, "Wait on condition");
            }
        }
        if (predicate_value != 0) {
            printf("doing some work: %d\n", i);
            ++i;
            predicate_value = 0;
        }
        status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        if (status != 0) {
            err_abort(status, "Unlock mutex");
        }
    }
}

int main () {
    int status = 0;
    pthread_t work_thread_id;
    status = pthread_create(&work_thread_id, NULL, do_work, NULL);
    if (status != 0) {
        err_abort(status, "Create work thread");
    }
    while (1) {
        status = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (predicate_value == 0) {
            if (status != 0) {
                err_abort(status, "Lock mutex main");
            }
            printf("%s\n", "changed value");
            predicate_value = 1;
            status = pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
            if (status != 0) {
                err_abort(status, "signal condition");
            }
        }
        status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        if (status != 0) {
            err_abort(status, "Unlock mutex main");
        }
        printf("%s\n", "time to sleep");
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the conditional

```c
if (predicate_value != 0)
```

in `do_work()` is unnecessary. The `while` loop only exits when `predicate_value` is non-zero.

We shouldn't have to worry about the content of `predicate_value` changing between the `while` and the `if`. When `pthread_cond_wait()` returns it locks the mutex so `predicate_value` is consistent until we unlock the mutex.

From the [pthread_cond_wait()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) docs:

> Upon successful return, the mutex shall have been locked and shall be owned by the calling thread.